# C# Bandwidth Throttling w/Azure

Tags: c#-4.0, azure-storage, bandwidth-throttling

I wrote a small utility that utilizes Azure blob storage to push some files across for a secondary backup (~100GB). Thus far it works really well, however since it is sitting in a colocation area, my bandwidth usage can hit 190mb/s+ which is a bill I'd rather not pay. Given this, I have two questions:

1. Outbound traffic on a server with multiple IPs utilizes the first IP configured as the "main" one. I know in C# I can get a list of network adapters and change properties, but is it possible to tell an app that it's traffic needs to utilize a specific IP (instead of the default) for outgoing connections? We could use this to filter anything coming out of that IP, regardless of destination and only this app would use that address.
2. If not, is it possible to configure an app to send all traffic on a separate adapter that would have a single IP, so we could filter outbound at our router level to throttle that traffic?

Alternatively (if we're attacking this from the wrong angle), is it possible to limit Azure transfers to a maximum bandwidth allotment in some capacity? That's all I'm really after, as any other traffic should be able to use the maximum it can (meaning QoS doesn't apply - there isn't contention here, just too much outgoing in general).

Answer (score 0):

For your backup needs, did you already evaluate RA-GRS, it provides built-in data replication to secondary location with read-only access on the data.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/

As far as I can tell there is no API allows you setup a limits for the bandwidth consumed, however you can enable storage monitoring so that you have a better idea on how many transactions triggered. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/

Btw, there is one thing which might be able to address your cost concern is to setup your spending limit for your Azure subscription, but this depends the type of your subscription. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/spending-limits/

Comment: I'm already using RA-GRS, and spending limits won't come into play since it's inbound data to Azure (and they only charge for outbound). The issue I'm running into is my colo facility bills at the 95th percentile usage, but they don't really have a cap - I can use whatever I want. Since Azure has massive connections, my bandwidth usage can go north of 160mb/s easily, and left to run, I get a massive bill from the colo provider.